# Wrap text for words under equation

Tags: math-mode, equations

I did this

```
   \begin{equation}

     Error(x) = \underbrace{ \left(E\left[\mathbb{E}\hat{f(x)}\right] - f(x)\right)^2}_\text{Bias^2; how much the predicted values differ from true values} \ \ +  \ \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{f}(x) - \mathbb{E}\left[\hat{f}(x)\right]\right]^2 }_\text{Variance; how the predictions made on the same value vary on different iterations of the model}

\end{equation}
```

But for the text looks whacky and does not wrap around. Not sure why this is not compiling anyways here is screen shot

[image]

Comment: you can not have blank lines in display math, also `\text` is like `\mbox` and makes a single line of text not a wrapped paragraph.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How would I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put the text in `\parbox`-es, though you have to specify their width (adjust to taste). There are ways of getting the precise width, but I think this is close enough for most purposes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
     \mathrm{Error}(x) = \underbrace{ \left(E\left[\mathbb{E}\hat{f}(x)\right] - f(x)\right)^2}_{\parbox{1.5in}{\centering Bias$^2$; how much the predicted values differ from true values}} \ \ +  \ \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{f}(x) - \mathbb{E}\left[\hat{f}(x)\right]\right]^2 }_{\parbox{1.5in}{\centering Variance; how the predictions made on the same value vary on different iterations of the model}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: parbox example]

Answer (score 5):

You can make a `\parbox`. The default width in this implementation is the same as the formula above the text, but the optional argument can be used to specify a fraction. Here `1.1` in both, but it can be different: experiment until you find a good compromise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\wrapunderbrace}[3][1]{{%
  \sbox0{$\displaystyle#2$}% measure the object to underbrace
  \underbrace{#2}_{%
    \parbox{#1\wd0}{\scriptsize\strut\ignorespaces#3}%
  }%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Error}(x) = 
\wrapunderbrace[1.1]{(E[\mathbb{E}\hat{f(x)}] - f(x))^2}{
  $\mathrm{Bias}^2$; how much the predicted values differ from true values
}
+
\wrapunderbrace[1.1]{\mathbb{E}[\hat{f}(x) - \mathbb{E}[\hat{f}(x)]]^2 }{
  Variance; how the predictions made on the same value vary 
  on different iterations of the model
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the output for

```
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Error}(x) =
\wrapunderbrace{(E[\mathbb{E}\hat{f(x)}] - f(x))^2}{
  $\mathrm{Bias}^2$; how much the predicted values differ from true values
}
+
\wrapunderbrace{\mathbb{E}[\hat{f}(x) - \mathbb{E}[\hat{f}(x)]]^2 }{
  Variance; how the predictions made on the same value vary
  on different iterations of the model
}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

I removed the `\left` and `\right` bits that only produce oversized fences.

Answer (score 2):

Don't ignore errors, if you get an error and choose to scroll past it you shouldn't look at the generated pdf xcept a possible debugging aid, it is not intended to be usable. If asking for help it's best to show a test document and the text of the error message, the output is less use.

You can not have blank lines in display math.

`\text` makes text so you can not have math such as `Bias^2` without nesting math such as `$\mathrm{Bias}^2$`

Not an error but don't use math italic for words such as Error, use `\mathrm`, or better hre `\operatorname`

Not an error but `\text` is like `\mbox` and makes a single line text box with no word wrapping.

Subscripts should be braced so `x_{\text{...}}` not `x_\text{...}` (this gives no error message but is wrong anyway and can lead to issues later.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

   \begin{equation}
    \operatorname{Error}(x) = 
\underbrace{(E[\mathbb{E}\hat{f(x)}] - f(x))^2}_
{\text{\parbox[t]{4cm}{\raggedright $\mathrm{Bias}^2$;
how much the predicted values differ from true values}}}
+
\underbrace{\mathbb{E}[\hat{f}(x) - \mathbb{E}[\hat{f}(x)]]^2 }_
{\text{\parbox[t]{4cm}{\raggedright Variance;
how the predictions made on the same value vary on different iterations of the model}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```